# Ajustar tempo para expirar $_SESSION

Tags: php, session

Como ajustar o tempo para expirar $_SESSION?

tentativas..

Incluir no top dos arquivos (funcionou no localhost offline)

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 3600); // 1 hora
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 3600);
session_start();
```

E também

```
session_set_cookie_params(3600); // 1 hora
session_start();
```

Alterar direto no **php.ini**

```
session.gc_maxlifetime = 3600
session.cookie_lifetime = 3600
```

mas nenhum dos métodos funcionaram no servidor Online

Answer (score 6):

No geral, utilizo sempre essa forma. Implementando um tempo limite na sessão:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['ultima_atividade']) && (time() - $_SESSION['ultima_atividade'] > 3600)) {

    // última atividade foi mais de 60 minutos atrás
    session_unset();     // unset $_SESSION  
    session_destroy();   // destroindo session data 
}
$_SESSION['ultima_atividade'] = time(); // update da ultima atividade
```

`session.gc_maxlifetime` e `session.cookie_lifetime`  não são confiáveis.

### Criando um simples código para deslogar ao expirar a sessão:

```
     session_start(); 

     ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', 0);

     if (!isset($_SESSION['name'])){
       $_SESSION['name']="Guest";

     }

     if ($_SESSION['name']!="Guest"){
        $counter = time();

        if (!isset($_SESSION['count'])){
          $_SESSION['count']= $counter;
        }

        if ($counter - $_SESSION['count'] >= 3600 ){
header('Location: http://www.meusite.com.br/sair.php');

       }
        $_SESSION['count']= $counter;

    }
```

[Leia mais clicando aqui.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: dúvida... ao destruir a session as variáveis setadas nela serão perdidas, e o usuário terá de refazer o processo caso ele tenha começado e parado até expirar o tempo, isso?

Comment: Claro. Quando expirar o tempo, a sessão é destruída.

Comment: legal @Lollipop, esse código devo por no arquivo que checa se o usuário está logado ou não né?

Comment: Atualizei, com base no seu comentário.