# O que são CRON JOBS e como usa-los com PHP

Tags: php, cron

Recentemente [fiz esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/225067/ajax-limitar-tempo-mesmo-dando-reload-na-p%C3%A1gina), mas eu achei meio que vulnerável usar os códigos que foram respondidos la, resumindo a melhor resposta: Cria um Cookie com um Tempo e esconde o botão, depois que este tempo esgotar, o botão volta. (Se algum atrevido limpar os `cookies` ele pode usar o sistema novamente).

Bom gostaria de fazer o mesmo usando `Cron` mas até agora eu não entendi o que são, e como usa-los pra executar um script a cada certo tempo, dando uma olhada aqui no SO, achei [este tópico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12793/como-fa%C3%A7o-para-executar-o-cron-jobs-no-php), porém para mim está em **"Japonês"**, gostaria de saber um exemplo simples, de `cron`, no caso com este raciocínio:

1. Verificar a quantidade de pessoas enviadas, (primeiro link da pergunta pra entender).
2. Verificar se a quantidade passou dos limits no caso usei na query `LIMIT 10`.
3. Executar o código, e esconde o botão (isso com javascript sei fazer).
4. Ao terminar de executar o código mostra uma mensagem "Volte em **x** minutos"
5. Depois de **x** minutos o botão reativa.

Espero que, expliquem o que é `cron` e um exemplo básico de como fazer oque eu quero, entenderam?

Answer (score 13):

Cron é um **agendador de tarefas** presente em sistemas Unix. Ele só faz isso: agenda tarefas para serem executadas em intervalos regulares.

Na resposta à sua pergunta te deram esse código:

```
59 23 * * * php -f /home/u844214382/cronjobs/nomedoarquivo.php
```

Ele pode ser traduzido como:

> Todos os dias, às `23` horas, no minuto `59`, execute o comando
>
> `php -f /home/u844214382/cronjobs/nomedoarquivo.php`

Você pode ver como criar esses e outras combinações de comandos usando esse site: https://crontab-generator.org/

`Cron` é uma ferramenta genérica do sistema. A **única** relação dele com o `PHP` se deve ao fato de que ele é capaz de disparar scripts no sistema, então você pode usá-lo para rodar scripts PHP na linha de comando também, como o exemplo indica.

Pra usar uma metáfora:

> Cron é um despertador. No intervalo que você mandar ele vai tocar e
> cutucar o seu script pra ele acordar. A partir daí o script se vira
> sozinho pra realizar as tarefas que tem que ser feitas.

Então as perguntas que você faz de 1 a 5 podem ser resolvidas no PHP puro, levando em conta que ele será executado na linha de comando (e não numa requisição vinda de um navegador), tendo o Cron apenas como agendador e disparador das tarefas.

Comment: Opa, já deu uma iluminada aqui, vamos ver o que consigo fazer com a sua resposta. Tem duas, qual eu conseguir, marco como resolvido.

Answer (score 6):

`Cron jobs` não tem nada a ver com seu problema, configurar uma `cron job` no servidor, simplismente faz que determinado script seja executado a cada `X` tempo.

Essa validação de tempo, só pode ser feita no cliente ou seja `javascript`, para ter um controle sobre isso seria nescessário, uma coluna no banco com valor `booleano` para o botão, e uma coluna do tipo `Date`, comparando o tempo que o botão foi acionado e o tempo que o usuário entrou na página novamente.

Outra alternativa seria limitar tempo na `sessão`, mas não seria tão preciso, até pq setar `sessões` consomem do teu servidor, então pq consumir em vários lugares, se pode consumir somente de um? [Tempo de sessões](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/54744/ajustar-tempo-para-expirar-session)

lembre-se que está tratando vários usuários em uma determinada página, você tera de ter o controle sob cada um individualmente.

Comment: Opa, já deu uma iluminada aqui, vamos ver o que consigo fazer com a sua resposta.