# Verificar data e hora em php

Tags: php

Minha duvida é como consultar data e hora com um IF para manipular um script em php no horario e dia programado.

Cheguei a fazer assim a principio funcionou mais n sei o que deu de errado depois. No exemplo abaixo seria executar todo sábado meio dia,

```html
if(date('D') == 'Sat' AND date('H:i') == '12:00') {
  echo"Isso é um teste";
}
```

Comment: Isso só será executado se for `12:00`, qualquer atraso fará isso não ser executado. Por mim, muito sentido essa construção. Primeiro, que o MySQL já possui um recurso para isso que é o [`MySQL Scheduled Event`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/events-overview.html) (não confundir Events com Triggers). Segundo, que isso poderia ser feito implicitamente quando o "player" requisitar a informação, se você tiver a data da "quest" e verificar que foi feita antes dessa semana atual, então deve ser "gerada uma nova quest" (se isso é o proposito do código, apenas deduzindo).

Comment: Na tese era para poder manipular a query pelo php.
Como haveria atraso?

Comment: Eu habilitei no mysql 
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;

Porem não consigo fazer com que o event faça todo sabado meio dia.

Comment: Faltou declarar o `date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');` Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Dessa forma como escreveu o código, o script só vai funcionar se ele for executado exatamente no sábado ao meio-dia, nota-se que alguém terá que executa-lo manualmente exatamente neste horário.

Caso sua intenção seja que ele seja executado automaticamente todo sábado ao meio dia terá que fazer isso através do servidor usando o CRON.

Aqui esta uma resposta mais detalhada sobre oque é o CRON e como usa-lo:
[O que são CRON JOBS e como usa-los com PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/225600/o-que-s%C3%A3o-cron-jobs-e-como-usa-los-com-php)